# Can the Ethereum network work only with pruned nodes?

Tags: security, state-trie-pruning

So if I got [state trie pruning](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/06/26/state-tree-pruning/) correctly, pruned nodes download all the block headers (so that they can check the PoW of the chain), the transactions of the last `k` (say 100) blocks (to resist against chain reorganisations/forks) and the state corresponding to the state Merkle root of the latest block.

With this technique, one can verify transactions just like full nodes, and without having to download the whole blockchain.

So my question is, would it be possible to have a network consisting only of pruned nodes, without jeopardizing security? In my intuition, even miners could correctly operate with a pruned blockchain.

Thank you for your help.